# clearing observable to hide content in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

In Knockout.js I am trying to create a list view and detail view by showing and hiding sections of my page.
Ive put together a jsfiddle of this, https://jsfiddle.net/jessebreuer/apn41oLc/
When you click on a name after adding some records it hides the list and shows the individual record. I now need to create a link to go back to the list view.
I have tried this:

```
<p data-bind="with: chosenFriend">
     <span data-bind="text: name" /></span>
     <span data-bind="click: chosenFriend('')">return to list</span>
</p>
```

But the code in the click event seems to keep the ifnot: chosenFriend section from hiding when I click on a name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you've bound the `click` binding to *the return value* of `chosenFriend('')` - ie that code will be executed at the time of the bindings being parsed.  You can bind to a function on your viewmodel in the same way you've done elsewhere in your view, and have that function call `chosenFriend('')`, or you can do it inline:

```
<p data-bind="with: chosenFriend">
     <span data-bind="text: name" /></span>
     <span data-bind="click: function() { $root.chosenFriend(''); }">return to list</span>
</p>
```